# How to place checkbox icon to left of text in checkable menu item in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, menuitem

I have a recylerview with a option button in every item. On button click a popup menu is shown. In popup menu there must be a checkbox and a delete button as item. First menu item is checkbox. I have used following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_watch"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:title="Watch"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
    android:title="Remove"
    app:showAsAction="withText|always"/>
</menu>
```

Problem is checkbox appears right of its text. I want it in left, but i can't. please help. TIA

Comment: I don't think that you should change it - it's a standard menu

Comment: @WadeWilson Please read the question - `Problem is checkbox appears right of its text. I want it in left, but i can't. please help`

Comment: You may set your own action view to show the custom view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. In case if anyone needs, i am giving it as a answer. First, set an unchecked checkbox as the icon of that menu item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_checkable"
        android:title="Check"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_unchecked_checkbox" />
</menu>
```

Then forcefully show the menu icon and title using this:

```
try {
    Class<?> classPopupMenu = Class.forName(popupMenu.getClass().getName());
    Field mPopup = classPopupMenu.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
    mPopup.setAccessible(true);
    Object menuPopupHelper = mPopup.get(popupMenu);
    Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper
                .getClass().getName());
    Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod("setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
    setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then change the icon and color of the menu while click on that icon. Keep track of check state using a boolean `isSelected`. Change the icon and it's color using this:

```
if(isSelected) {
    MenuItem checkable = (MenuItem) popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_checkable);
    Drawable checkableDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_checked_checkbox);
    checkableDrawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    checkable.setIcon(checkableDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With above way not possible because Left section already allocated to title and icon.

If you want to display popup with checkbox then you can use Alertdialog with checkbox using adapter.

Or

You can use listview inside popup view.

Comment: Is it possible to place checkbox to left of title and icon?

Comment: Sorry but with menu not possible

Comment: Thanks, at least i learn that it's not possible how i wanted to do.